# What is the appropriate mechanism to reach SFF "management"?

Tags: support, stackexchange

I would like to pitch an idea to "SFF management", so to speak - presumably, the moderators + SFF community liaison from StackExchange (assuming one still exists).

What would be an appropriate mechanism for doing so privately<sup>[1]</sup>?

I thought about using a moderator flag but that'd be a wrong tool AND is too limited (text size) for reasonable communication.

On a separate note, if "management" should be a different set of people, please include that in the answer as well.

<sub>[1] - I don't want to subject myself to public ridicule if the idea is shot down :)</sub>

**UPDATE** - Apologies for confusion, the idea is mostly in the area of site promotion, which is why my emphasis is on Stack Exchange discussion as oppose to meta.

Comment: What happened to @BrettWhite?

Comment: @OghmaOsiris - See my other META question: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2174/who-is-the-community-liaison-for-sff-from-se

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no easy way to reach the moderators privately except for flagging.

To get someone from SE, write a mail to team@stackexchange.com. This will reach someone from [the community team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do) (Aarthi, Shog9, Grace Note, Anna Lear, Robert Cartaino and Jaydles). If it is related to promoting the site, it might be forwarded to CHAOS. There is no specific liasion for each site.

But if you want to propose a feature, the community team will almost certainly just tell you to put it up on meta. They usually want to gather the opinion of the community before acting.

Comment: this is more of a promotion related item than a feature request. Does CHAOS have a mail alias?

Comment: @DVK Start with a meta post. Especially promotion-related ideas are handy to have vetted by the community. We'll pass the link along to anyone who needs to be involved from the company.

Comment: @AnnaLear - I appreciate the advice; but I have what I think are good reasons not to publically air it **until I get an A-OK** from Stack Exchange, none of which have to do with possible disapproval by the community (one is, for example, the fact that the most likely the answer from SE will be "not feasible" and I don't want to waste my or anyone's time with extended meta discussion). I could be wrong of course. I will email CHAOS if I can find the email; and give them a summary; they can always tell me to go away and not to bother them till META discussion happens.

Comment: @DVK Email team@stackexchange.com then. We'll forward it along. CHAOS doesn't really have an email per se.

Answer (score 2):

So, let's talk about some potential problems, and what the proper thing to do about them is.

**New idea-** Ultimately, any new idea should be passed on through the meta site, at least one coming from users. It might be a good idea to flesh it out, especially if it is rather complex. I suggest that one brings it up in the chatroom in that case.

**Problem question** Just flag it, and a moderator will assist as best as we can.

**Problem user** There might be a need to discuss a problem with a user. The best thing in this case seems to be to set up a message in chat, and ask a moderator. We are all there pretty often, and can be there sooner if needed.

**Problem moderator** I hope this isn't the case here, but there are mechanisms to reach stack exchange employees. I would suggest that you find a friendly moderator on another site and discuss the situation, if there is a legitimate problem. Still, I would start with a meta post to understand what is going on. Only if there was some extreme action, which is very unlikely to be just one moderator, would it be worth a single user talking directly to stack exchange.

Remember, that while Stack Exchange gets the money, and writes the checks, this is really owned in most senses by the community. The community needs to be involved in changes, as much as can be done.

Comment: If there is an issue with a moderator, discussing it with a moderator on another site won't be terribly helpful. Contacting us (as in, the community team) is the way to go in that case. Use the "contact us" link at the bottom of every page to reach us.

Comment: Didn't realize there was such a button, so...

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto - sorry for being too vague. It's an idea that can't be VERY neatly categorized but is more related to site promotion than anything else. The user community is largely irrelevant in this specific case, since the issues to be discussed mostly relate to whether the idea is a good thing **from SE point of view and mostly whether SE as a company can help implement it** (to be honest, even the moderators don't need to be involved, but I wanted to include them to not seem rude and going over their head).

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto - To respond to your wording, the idea is NOT in need of fleshing out (already fleshed out) and is **not complex at all** at the core - only implementing it is complex. HOWEVER, if the idea is accepted by Stack, some of the peripheral implementation details - which are more relevant to SFF community than SE company - will be discussed on meta.

Answer (score 0):

You can request a moderator make a private room for you + the moderator(s), but this is a tool that's only supposed to be used for real *issues of moderation* such as suspected sockpuppets or other user abuse that can't easily be described in a single flag.

If you just have an idea I'd post it up on Meta so everyone can see and evaluate it.